# Map Collection of Interface using annotation in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, interface, annotations

I have an interface called `Rule` with 2 implementing classes who all share one Abstract base class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public interface Rule { .. }

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseRule implements Rule {

@Entity
public class ImlementingRule1 extends BaseRule { 

@Entity
public class ImlementingRule1 extends BaseRule {
```

I'm using this `Rule` interface in a containgRules class as such:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "RULES_ID")
private List<Rule> rules;
```

Whatever setup I try I always end up with:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Cannot use identity column key generation with <union-subclass> mapping for: mynamespace.BaseRule
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally have found no other solution than to use the abstract base class, instead of interface.

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "RULES_ID")
private List<BaseRule> rules;
```

It states [right here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1168):

> Annotating interfaces is currently not supported.